# Partial instantiation of a type-class via constraints on its arguments

Tags: haskell, types, higher-kinded-types

Consider a kind `m : * -> *` and assume that I know how to define (let's say) a monadic structure on `m`, but only when its arguments satisfy some constraint `C`, for instance `Eq`. In other words, I have a function

```
(>>=) :: => m a -> (a -> m b) -> b`
```

that satisfies the monad laws, but in order to define it I would need to have `(Eq a, Eq b)`.

Unfortunately, the definition

```
instance Monad m where
    (>>=) :: (Eq a, Eq b) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> b
```

is considered illegal. This is a bummer because I only plan on using `m` on `Eq`-types, and this condition could easily be statically checked.

Is there some way to get around this? Either conceptually, or practically?

Many thanks

Comment: May be [`{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-InstanceSigs) language extension can help you.

Comment: @Redu `InstanceSigs` won't help. Quoting the docs: "The type signature in the instance declaration must be more polymorphic than (or the same as) the one in the class declaration, instantiated with the instance type".

Comment: In brief, it is not really possible with the usual `Monad` class. The suggested questions and their answers cover a number of possible workarounds.